# Tableview design problems

Tags: xcode, uitableview, tableview

I got a page setup with `TableView`, and I made it so when I press a cell, I will see the "sub" cells open up and if I press it again, they will close again. to make it easy to see which ones are open, I wanted them to turn grey instead of white, but unfortunately, some of the cells that are not opened and are not pressed yet are still grey, and it changed which ones that are messed up from time to time when i open the app.

So I'm hoping someone have a good idea of how to fix this or a great tutorial on tableview designing that covers this? I'll paste in the the part of the code that does the color change.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var dataIndex = indexPath.row - 1
    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {return UITableViewCell()}
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].title
        return cell

    } else {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {return UITableViewCell()}
        cell.textLabel?.text = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sectionData[dataIndex]
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

        return cell

    }

}
```

Comment: Don't put code outside SO; insert it in your question.

Comment: what exactly you want ?expandable tableview?

Comment: You are recycling cells so it may happen that you sometimes get a recycled grey cell! At least enforce coloring in the other case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Important:** Don't add image of your code. Remove it and add the code in the question. It will be easy to help.

Now in the code what you have done is you are adding color to cell :

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
```

but when the cell is getting reused you are not changing it to default color.

Add below code for default colors (white in your case) :

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Comment: That really make sense, I updated with that, and now it works as I wanted it to, never thought about making sure that the default color should be set.
I have updated the post to include the code instead of a picture (couldn’t get it to do that properly, but now I found out how to do it).

Thank you all of You for the help, I really appreciate it